# How to use \patchcmd to change section size in an AMS Article?

Tags: formatting, fontsize, etoolbox, amsart

I am trying to change the size of the section title in the AMS Article document class from `\normalsize` to `\large.` Here is what I tried:

```
\documentclass[]{amsart}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\section}{\normalsize}{\large}{}{}
\begin{document}

\section{Section}
Content.

\end{document}
```

However, this doesn't change anything. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\section` command is defined in `amsart.cls` as:

```
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{.7\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont\scshape\centering}}
```

So we can replace `\normalfont` with `\normalfont\Large` to increase the size of the font.

`\patchcmd` works with the form `\patchcmd{<command>}{<findtext>}{<replacewiththis>}{}{}`.  The last two brackets are "success" and "failure" code blocks that aren't often needed for these types of changes.  As you can see, it becomes useful to see the original definition of the command, in order to alter specific sections to include or change elements as you desire.

The code becomes:

```
\documentclass[]{amsart}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\section}{\normalfont}{\normalfont\Large}{}{}
\begin{document}

\section{Section}
Content.

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image: new]

as opposed to the old size:

[image: old]

Comment: Cool, I was wondering about that. I looked up the documentation for `\patchcmd` but not for `amsart` so I didn't know which parameters to use.

Comment: By the way -- I'm out of votes right now.... but there's always tomorrow :)

Comment: Haha no worries cslstr.

Comment: It's the thought that counts.